# Existence of $n$ reals such that $\sum f'(x_k) = n$

Tags: calculus

The problem is the following :

Let $f$ be a function continuously differentiable on $[0,1]$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1) = 1$.

It is asked to prove that for all naturals $ n \ge 1$ there exists $n$ reals $x_i$ such that

$$\begin{cases} 0<x_1<x_2<\cdots<x_n<1 \\
\displaystyle\sum f'(x_i) =n \end{cases}$$

I tried induction starting from $n=1$ which follows from the MVT.

I'm stuck with the inductive step.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us what you have so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint:* Induction is not needed here. Write
$$
1 = f(1) - f(0) = \sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)- f\left(\frac{k-1}{n}\right)
$$
and then apply the mean-value theorem to $f$ on each interval $(\frac{k-1}{n}, \frac{k}{n})$.

Comment: +1.  I recall one textbook that uses this principle for a nice proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus for Riemann integrals.